# Envoy proxy is using too much memory

Tags: kubernetes, envoyproxy

Envoy is using all the memory and the pods are getting evicted. Is there a way to set limit to how much memory envoy proxy can use in the envoy configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably do that by configuring the `overload-manager` in the `bootstrap` configuration for Envoy. Here's a [documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/operations/overload_manager/overload_manager#overload-manager) link for more details. It is done simply by adding `overload-manager` section as follows:

```
overload_manager:
  refresh_interval: 0.25s
  resource_monitors:
  - name: "envoy.resource_monitors.fixed_heap"
    typed_config:
      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.resource_monitors.fixed_heap.v3.FixedHeapConfig
      # TODO: Tune for your system.
      max_heap_size_bytes: 2147483648  # 2 GiB <==== fix this!
  actions:
  - name: "envoy.overload_actions.shrink_heap"
    triggers:
    - name: "envoy.resource_monitors.fixed_heap"
      threshold:
        value: 0.95
  - name: "envoy.overload_actions.stop_accepting_requests"
    triggers:
    - name: "envoy.resource_monitors.fixed_heap"
      threshold:
        value: 0.98
```